# Why should we put a Lambda that talks to external services in a VPC?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html, if a Lambda requires access to either public AWS resources, or resources on the internet, it should be placed inside a VPC. I can't find (or think of) a good reason to do so, if invocation of my Lambda is already limited by APIGateway or IAM permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure where you read that in the link.

If you look at the diagram in that link:

[image: using VPC logic]

It first says that if you only need resources that are outside of the VPC, then do not put it on the VPC.  The bottom part of the diagram says, "if you need access to public AND private resources", then set up the VPC and also a NAT.

Long story short, if you only need access to public resources, do not put the Lambda inside the VPC. It adds several seconds of delay at start and gives you no benefit unless you need to access another resources in the VPC.

Comment: Reading comprehension failure on my part entirely.